# RabbitMQ: enabling plugins creates new default vhost "/"

Tags: rabbitmq

enabling rabbitmq_event_exchange plugin creates (?) new virtual host named "/", while there is already defined default vhost named "VLAN". How to enable this plugin on "VLAN"... and not create "/" vhost ?

Comment: Any time you are asking a question about RabbitMQ (or any software), it's **vital** that you state the version you're using. In the case of RabbitMQ, you should also include the Erlang version.

I can't reproduce the issue you report. Please see this repository:

https://github.com/lukebakken/rabbitmq-enabling-plugins-creates-new-default-vhost-73318918

The `Dockerfile` defines an image where the `rabbitmq_event_exchange` plugin is enabled well after RabbitMQ starts. Note that the configuration file defines `foobar` as the `default_vhost`

Comment: NOTE: the RabbitMQ team monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.